# why there is no default google task integration with evolution mail?

Tags: android, evolution, google

I have found an application on android device which is having an better integration on Android device which is named as Task and this application is developed by TAM TASKS how does this team are able to sync the task from the android device to the google, they don't have any problem in this, so can somebody can dig into it so that this same function can be achieved from evolution by developing any plugin for it.
The product is listed on this url:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks&hl=en[enter link description here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to pay someone to program it, or do it your self you really shouldn't complain about lack of features.

That said, you can use KDE PIM if you must have a desktop mail client that supports google tasks.